# Origen de escarlata como sinónimo de rojo

Tags: significado, sinónimos, colores

La palabra [*escarlata*](https://dle.rae.es/escarlata?m=form) desde el DLE presenta una etimología bastante clara

> Del ár. hisp. iškarláṭ[a], este del gr. bizant. σιγιλλᾶτος sigillâtos 'tejido de lana o lino adornado con marcas en forma de anillos o círculos', y este del lat. [textum] sigillātum '[paño] sellado o marcado'.

Sin embargo no muestra por parte alguna el concepto de "rojo". ¿De dónde viene el significado y la sinonimia con el rojo?

Comment: Parece que *escarlata* es difícil (http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/2359/); *colorado* supongo que viene de lo que a uno le pasa cuando siente pena.

Comment: @aparente001:  Sobre el origen de "scarlatta" con el significado de "color rojo encendido" el *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* algo explica ([1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00865.jpg) y [2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00866.jpg)).

Comment: @aparente001:  Más que cuando uno siente pena, cuando uno se ruboriza. No sé si la raíz "rub-", también presente en el adjetivo latín ["rubens"](https://www.nihilscio.it/manuali/lingua%20latina/verbi/Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=rubens), que significa precisamente "rojo" tendrá algo que ver.

Comment: Donde he escrito "scarlatta" antes, debería poner "scarlatto" :(sorry!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como se puede ver en el [diccionario Sabatini Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/scarlatto.shtml), en italiano existen el sustantivo "scarlatto" y el adjetivo "scarlatto/scarlatta", que en la lengua actual se usan para referirse a un color rojo intenso y brillante, aunque a lo largo de la historia han tenido algún  otro uso.

El [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00866.jpg)  (un [enorme diccionario](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_dizionario_della_lingua_italiana) que goza de gran prestigio, iniciado en 1961 y completado en 2002, al que después se le añadieron los suplementos de 2004 y de 2009 que incorporan nuevas palabras) da la siguiente etimología para este vocablo (es esencialmente la misma etimología que da el DLE para "escarlata", pero explica el significado de la palabra árabe; nótese también que realmente está explicando la etimología del francés "escarlate" porque el término italiano se introdujo a partir del francés):

> =  Persiano-ar. 
>   *saqirlāt* ‘abito  tinto  di  rosso  con  la  coc­ciniglia’  (dal  biz.  *σιγιλλάτος,  che  a  sua  volta  è  dal  lat. *[textum] sigillatum*)
>    per il tramite del fr. *escarlate*; cfr. an­che lat. mediev. *scarlactum* (nel 1259).

Es decir, nos dice que proviene del persa-árabe *saqirlāt*, que significa ropa teñida de rojo con el carmín proveniente de la cochinilla, palabra que procede del bizantino *σιγιλλάτος, que a su vez viene del latín *[textum] sigillatum*, a través del francés *escarlate* (cfr. también con el latín medieval *scarlactum*, palabra documentada desde 1259).

El [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00865.jpg) explica también del italiano "scarlatto"

> in  origine  il  termine,  riferito 
>   esclusivamente  ad  abiti,  indicava anche  una  par­ticolare  varietà  di  tessuto

es decir, que originariamente el término, que se refería exclusivamente a ropa (se refiere al italiano, pero, teniendo en cuenta la información del *Trésor de la langue française* indicada más abajo, probablemente ocurrió lo mismo con el castellano "escarlata" a partir de algún momento), indicaba también una particular variedad de tejido. Se refiere a la acepción número 3 del diccionario:

> Tessuto pregiato di lana generalmente tinto in grana

que traduzco como "tejido de lana preciado habitualmente teñido con grana" ("grana" es el colorante  que se obtiene de la cochinilla). El diccionario da a continuación una serie de citas literarias de autores medievales, renacentistas y también de épocas más recientes que usan esta acepción de "scarlatto".

Así mismo, el [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/%C3%A9carlate) explica

> En Occident ar. puis en Occident chrét., l'écarlate vint à désigner un tissu riche de n'importe quelle couleur, puis un tissu rouge du fait de l'utilisation de la teinture à base de cochenille (au XII<sup>e</sup>  s., Almeria en Espagne fut l'un des centres de production les plus importants), de là le sens actuel de « couleur rouge »

es decir, en el occidente árabe y después en el occidente cristiano, con "escarlata" se designaba inicialmente un tejido preciado de cualquier color y, más adelante un tejido de color rojo por el uso de tintes procedentes de la cochinilla (en el siglo XII, Almería, en España, fue uno de los centros de producción más importantes), de donde procede el significado actual de "color rojo".